# How to use softmax at output layer of neural network?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, softmax

How can I use trained data of ANN with softmax as the output layer? Is it possible with Matlab inbuilt neural network tool (nnstart)?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. What are you trying to do? You can, for sure, use a softmax layer as output layer in a neural network. Matlab has a neural network toolkit which can do this for you. Take a look at: https://nl.mathworks.com/help/nnet/examples/create-simple-deep-learning-network-for-classification.html

Comment: I am using inbuilt ANN of matlab( nnstart command->Pattern Recognition Tool),I can not change it's output layer, I do not have any matlab implementation of ANN in matlab so.....